# Can't find the question where I upvoted a comment from someone

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, voting

Is there a way to find the Question where I only upvoted a comment?

Hours after I upvoted a comment I've found good information on that question. Now there was no way to find that question again.

I thought I can go to my profile, click on votes and will find my comment upvote. But there are only upvotes on questions and or answers but not on comments.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to find the question again where I only upvoted one comment?

Comment: No, you cannot; comments are second-class citizens and not searchable. Comment votes are third-class citizens..

Comment: perhaps click on the Activity tab

Comment: @MartijnPieters if I click on activity, comments, I can search trough the comments

Comment: @caramba: You can see your comments there, but you cannot search through all of them using a site search. Your browser will let you search through the text currently displayed, yes, but that won't let you find older comments not shown on the particular page you are on. And those are only *your own* comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for this exact explanation. What do you mean by "search trough all of them using a site search"? On my Profile I can see all comments I left somewhere. Now for me, it would be (for what happend, explained in the question) real awesome to find those questions where I only upvoted a comment

Comment: search your browsing history maybe

Comment: Bottom line: no such way exist. Next time just remember to click  the star as well. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard don't want to click on every question star where I upvote a comment

Comment: @caramba sure, but if you feel the question is useful favorite it, then once in a while clean your list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's a good point, (it wasn't a useful question) I just kind of rememberd and found something useful so I wanted to get back to it and share. Bolus comment did the trick! Still, it would be nice to have an easy way to get back on upvoted comments as I can search trough my posted comments etc.

Answer (score 8):

Not through stack exchange directly, no. However comments are indexed on Google so you can try googling:

```
 site:http://meta.stackoverflow.com "{comment text here}"
```

That should give you a list of results that include the comment text, so hopefully you can find it from there. It's worked for me in the past anyway.

Comment: +1 verry nice, didn't even think of trying something like that (but don't remeber the comment text :) )

Comment: @caramba Don't worry, by the time you find it you'll have forgotten what you wanted to do with it ;-)

Comment: @caramba: Ah yes, that is the drawback of this approach!